# Display mysql database on table on PDF using FPDF PHP

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

im aiming to display a data on table form on PDF using FPDF( no *"Cell"* is used). the issue is not acceptable to use *"echo"* in PDF creatingto create the table.

any ideas?

Comment: just create string instead echoing table. if you really want to use echo, you can use output buffering `ob_start();echo "foo"; echo "bar"; $html = ob_get_clean();`

Answer (score 0):

```
 // retrieve student data
            $student = new Student();
            $id = 1;
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name, email FROM student WHERE ID = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($student->name, $student->email);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->close();

            // retrieve grades
            $stmt = prepare("SELECT course_title, letter_grade FROM databas WHERE student_id = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);

            $stmt->bind_result($course_title, $letter_grade);
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                $student->grades[] = array("course_title" => $course_title, "letter_grade" => $letter_grade);
            }
            $stmt->close();

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT course_title, letter_grade FROM javascript WHERE student_id = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($course_title, $letter_grade);
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                $student->grades[] = array("course_title" => $course_title, "letter_grade" => $letter_grade);
            }
            $stmt->close();

            // generate PDF
            $pdf = new PDF();
            $pdf->AliasNbPages();
            $pdf->AddPage();

            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
            $pdf->Cell(0,10,'Name of the student : '.$student->name,0, 0, 'L');
            $pdf->Cell(0,10,'Date : '.date('d-m-Y'),0, 0, 'R');

            $pdf->Ln(5);
            $pdf->Cell(35,10,'Student ID : '.$id,0, 0);
            $pdf->Ln();


            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
            foreach ($student->grades as $grade) {
                $pdf->Cell(70,10,$grade["course_title"],0, 0);
                $pdf->Cell(70,10,$grade["letter_grade"],0, 0);
                $pdf->Ln();
            }

            $pdf->Ln(10);
            $pdf->Cell(0, 10, 'Signature: ________________________', 0, 1, 'R');

            $pdf->Output();
            ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).